# Is it possible to create a block using xsl fo with only a background color but no text content?

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am trying to create a box with rounded corners filled with color using xsl fo, apache fop library. I tried using "background-color" but that works only with text in a block. Same thing if I try using table cells. Please provide a way to get a background color with no text etc.

```
<fo:block-container absolute-position="absolute" top="2.7172in" left="1.7228in" width="0.5361in" height="0.2713in" display-align="center" border-color="black" border-style="solid" fox:border-radius="6pt">
<fo:block background-color="#aaaaff">.</fo:block>
</fo:block-container>
```

Gives an empty box with no color.

Answer (score 1):

Put the `background-color` property on the `fo:block-container`, since that's the area that you are trying to fill.